# Printing an arrays values after the user input

Tags: java, arrays

The array is printing before the user inputs their guess. I'm sure it's in the wrong spot. I need the array to record the number of guesses then when the user finally guesses the right number, I need it to print out the number of tries it took. Ultimately I will add rounds but I want to make sure I can make the array print out correctly before I do that.

```
// "Guess My Number"
import java.util.Random; //program uses random 
import java.util.Scanner; //program uses scanner

public class GuessMyNumber{
     public static void main(String[] args){
            Scanner input = new Scanner ( System.in );
            int randomNum;
            int userNum;
            int counter;
            Random randomNumbers = new Random();
            randomNum = 1 + randomNumbers.nextInt(11);
            counter = 1;

            System.out.println( "Enter a number (no decimals) from 1 to 1000: \n" );
            userNum = input.nextInt();

            int[] guess;
            guess = new int[ 99 ];//array of 100 guesses
            for (int guesses = 0; guesses < guess.length; guesses++ ){
                    System.out.printf("%5d%8d\n", guesses, guess[guesses] );
            }
            while (userNum != randomNum){
                  if (userNum < randomNum){    
                           System.out.printf( "%d is too low! Please pick another number.\n",            userNum);
                           ++counter;
                  }
                  else if (userNum > randomNum){
                          System.out.printf("%d is too high! Please pick another number.\n", userNum);
                          ++counter;
                  }
                          userNum = input.nextInt(); 
            }
            System.out.println( "\nCongratulations! You guessed the right number.\n");
            System.out.printf( "It took you %d tries!", counter);
     }        
}
```

Comment: What trouble is that?

Comment: I'm *guessing* all your outputs are '0'?

Comment: Your code totally works, and prints out a bunch of zeros. What did you expect to happen?

Comment: @JeroenVannevel Haha, very nice.

Comment: Your code works perfectly . guess[] values was initialized by default to '0' automatically. what's you problem ?

Comment: I have clarified what I need...(I hope!)

Answer (score 2):

You need to assign a value to each element of 'guess'.

```
for (...) {
    guess[guesses] = guesses; // or something else
    System.out.printf(...)
}
```

Comment: initialized by default to '0' automatically

Comment: I'm creating a numbers guessing game and will use an array to track the number of guesses for each round. I guess I'm having trouble on how to assign the values to each element of 'guess'.

Comment: As mentioned above, the code works so I'm assuming the problem he has is everything is 0... and looks funny, ex. 99    0.

Comment: @Octovamp edit your post and explain what you want exactly !!

Comment: Ok I've edited the post. I'm took Java 1 over a year ago and I'm having trouble keeping up with Java 2.